# Number of ways to assign $n + 1$ to $n$ teaching assistants if each T. A. can have more than one student

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose there are $n + 1$ students and $n$ teaching assistants (T.A.'s). So how many ways can we assign the students to T.A.'s when each T.A. can have more than $1$ student?

When I did it, I thought about it as a combinations problem and got $C(2n, n)$, but I am not sure if that is the answer.

Comment: Does each TA  can has atleast 1 student

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What's TA here? Your language is ambiguous too.

Comment: Does each TA have to have at least one student?

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha  A T.A. is a teaching assistant, usually a graduate student who teaches undergraduate students.

Comment: Students and teaching assistants are people, so they are distinguishable.  Therefore, it matters which teaching assistant is assigned to which student.  Your answer appears to be an attempt to determine how many students are assigned to each teaching assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Since students and teaching assistants are people, they are distinguishable.  Since there are $n$ possible teaching assistants to which each student could be assigned, there are $n^{n + 1}$ possible assignments of teaching assistants to students.

It appears that you ignored the fact that students are distinguishable.  If we were only interested in how many students are assigned to each teaching assistant, then the number of possible assignments is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = n + 1$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_j$ is the number of students assigned to the $j$th teaching assistant.  Since a particular solution of that equation corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n + 1$ ones, there are
$$\binom{n + 1 + n - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{2n}{n - 1}$$
ways to do that because we must choose which $n - 1$ of the $2n$ positions required for $n + 1$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.